# What does the superscript plus/minus in limit notation really mean?

Tags: calculus, limits, notation, terminology

I'm a beginner calc student, and I see limits in this context:
$$\lim_{x\to n^+}f(x)$$

In my class and in most videos I find online, it means "approaching $n$ from the right", but some people say it means "$x$ is a number infinitesimally larger than $n$", and vice versa for $n^-$.

Are these interchangeable, or is one correct?

Comment: If you are working with the standard real number line, it means approaching $n$ from the right (and the notion of "infinitesimally larger" doesn't make sense). There is a subject called non-standard analysis, which extends the notion of real number and makes it meaningful to talk about infinitesimal quantities, but you are not likely to be doing non-standard analysis in a beginner's course.

Comment: "approaching $n$ from the right" is the correct interpretation with *right* meaning *larger* here.  $x-n$ becomes arbitrarily small but remains positive

Comment: For $L\neq\pm\infty$, $L=\lim_{x\to a^\pm}f(x)$ iff for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that$$0<\pm(x-a)<\delta\implies|f(x)-L|<\epsilon.$$By contrast, $\lim_{x\to a^\pm}f(x)=\pm'\infty$ iff for all $N>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that$$0<\pm(x-a)<\delta\implies\pm'f(x)>N.$$(This all assumes $a\ne\pm\infty$; $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}f(x):=\lim_{x\to0^\pm}f(1/x)$.)

Answer (score 1):

In the real numbers, there is no such thing as a value that is "infinitesimally larger" (or smaller) than another. There are constructions and systems like non-standard analysis that add infinitesimal values to the real numbers, but typically that's *not* what is going on unless explicitly stated.

The notation $\lim_{x \rightarrow a^+} f(x)$ means "the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $a$ from above", or in other words it is the limit where you consider only values of $x > a$. On the real number line you can swap "from above" with "from the right", but that may get confusing if you're working in the Cartesian plane and taking a limit on $y$, for example.

Similarly, $\lim_{x \rightarrow a^-} f(x)$ would be considered "the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $a$ from below", and then $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)$ exists if and only if the limits from above and below both exist, and are equal to one another.

Answer (score 0):

infinitesimal refers to an extremely small value approaching zero. "infinitesimally larger" isn't a valid concept. The notation in which you listed is read as "the limit of f(x) as x approaches n from the right. You would be correct that if it was an - instead + that it would be from the left.